Has any US prosecutor before Jack Smith ever dropped a case on account of the defendant winning an election?
Special counsel Jack Smith will reportedly drop the outstanding criminal cases against Donald Trump, related to classified documents and the attempt to overturn the results of the 2020 election, on the basis that those cases will not conclude before Trump is inaugurated.
It's widely expected that once Trump is inaugurated, he will appoint an Attorney General who would drop those cases, and even if not, longstanding DoJ policy prevents action against a sitting president. So everyone understands that if Smith didn't drop the cases, they would still not continue anyway. Still, it is clear that if Trump had not won the election then Smith would not have decided to drop the cases.
Is there any precedent in the US for a prosecutor dropping a case as a consequence of the defendant winning an election? Comparable examples might include:

In a state where the state Attorney General is appointed by the Governor, they might drop a case against the governor-elect.
In a state where the state Attorney General is directly elected, they might drop a case against their own successor.
Or, any situation where a prosecutor decides that pursuing such a case is no longer in the public interest.

I am well aware that the Presidency confers a unique immunity from federal criminal investigation and prosecution, due to DoJ policy and the Supreme court ruling Trump v. US. This question is not specifically about the Presidency. For a case to be comparable for the purposes of this question, it need not involve immunity, only a decision by a prosecutor to drop a case against a defendant, either directly or indirectly because the defendant won an election.

Have there ever been any other candidates running while subject to criminal investigation in the first place? I can't find any, although a few have been indicted or convicted before running: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2023/04/01/trump-presidential-candidates-ran-under-indictment/11582983002/

To add on to what was already mentioned, has there ever been another candidate who was under investigation/prosecution that got elected to a position that made them immune (or at least policy would prevent it) from being investigated/prosecuted?

@JoeW I intentionally didn't limit the question to the presidency, as I know that other examples would need to be for lower offices. The Guardian article quotes former AG Bill Barr as saying "The American people have rendered their verdict on President Trump and decisively chosen him to lead the country for the next four years. They chose him to lead us with the full knowledge of the claims against him by prosecutors around the country" ─ that justification is based on the will of the people, not immunity granted to the office-holder, so Barr's argument would apply to other offices too.

See for example how some charges against Flynn were dropped https://edition.cnn.com/2020/05/07/politics/michael-flynn-prosecution/index.html If you leave aside that Flynn was an adviser and not himself elected.

@264champagnebottlesonice If there is a long list of cases where the defendant won an election, causing the prosecutor to decide that pursuing the case was no longer in the public interest, then you could write an answer about one or some of those cases. The question is not asking for a comprehensive list.

If we'll permit broadening to something of the reverse situation, where an exiting President goes uncharged because they were President, then President Clinton was offered a plea deal rather than being charged after he left office because the prosecutor didn't like the optics of prosecuting a former President (especially not in DC, which loved Clinton, so a jury might refuse to convict him as a result).
And Ford pardoned Nixon for much the same reasons (except Nixon was definitely not loved in DC).
I'm not aware of any other Presidents that were given a pass because it was deemed too problematic to go after them.  It seems plausible others were, at least, but Clinton and Nixon are the two we have clear evidence for, rather than clues and supposition.  Warren G. Harding has, perhaps until recently, been long considered to have led the most corrupt administration in US history (the Teapot Dome scandal being the most well-known, but hardly all there was).  But he was never charged, probably due to his dying in office, and to this day whether or not he was complicit in or even aware of much of the corruption is a matter of debate and uncertainty (he was made aware of the Veteran's Bureau scandal while alive, at least, and responded questionably to it by letting the perpetrator flee to Europe). There seems to be more of a modern day lean to considering him an earnest, hardworking President who deserves a lot of praise for his accomplishments in a Post-WW1 world, and who mostly just happened to make bad choices about who to appoint and trust; and had an affair. He was one of the most popular presidents in history when he died in 1923, late in his first term, but opinion soon soured once the scandals broke.
